# How can I dynamically generate DOM elements using ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have array with thee values:

```
let elements = ["div", "span", "button"]
```

How can I dynamically generate these elements in DOM using `forEach` or `map`  iterator in ReactJS?

So as output I want to have:

```html
<div> Value1 <div>
<span> Value 2 </span>
<button> Click me! </button>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `createElement` directly, rather than writing JSX (which does that under the hood):

```js
const Test = (props) => {
    let elements = ["div", "span", "button"];
    return (
        <div>
            {
                elements.map((el, index) => 
                    React.createElement(el, { key: index }, "hello"))
            }
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

From [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement):

> ```
> React.createElement(type, [props], [...children])
> ```
>
> Create and return a new React element of the given type. The type argument can be either a tag name string (such as 'div' or 'span'), or a React component type (a class or a function).

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* want to do that, it's as simple as

```
React.createElement('div', {attribute: 'value'}, [children])
```

Just replace `'div'` with your variable. [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)

Answer (score 0):

I have found [Gaurav Singhal](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-render-a-component-dynamically-based-on-a-json-config) sharing great example in terms of how to use `React.createElement`:

```
let WelcomeText = React.createElement(
  "h1",
  { style: { color: "blue" } },
  "This is a welcome text"
);
```

This will lead you to have

```
<h1 style="color:blue">
  This is a welcome text
</h1>
```

but if you are just beginner or slow learner like me, and somehow you just need more reference to know whether there is alternative way, I have found [Corentin de Boisset](https://blog.theodo.com/2016/02/introduction-to-react/) and [array.map()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58793514/react-play-media-after-items-are-loaded-with-array-map) both introducing how to use `array.map()` in JSX, I myself also use array.map() to play video in JSX and it works:

```
    constructor (props) {
      super (props);
      this.state = {playList = []}
    }

    render() {
        let dynamicPlayer = this.state.playList.map((items) => {
            return (
                <ReactPlayer
                url= {items.source}//'storage/star_war.mp4'
                className='react-player'
                width='100%'
                height='100%'
                volume={items.volume}
                controls = {true}
                />)
        })

        return (
            <Container>
                <div>{dynamicPlayer}</div>
            </Container>
        );
    }
```

Though I would recommend `React.createElement` as well.