# React - play media after items are loaded with array.map()

Tags: reactjs, react-player

I'm using [react-player](https://github.com/CookPete/react-player) to render youtube videos with `map()`, like so:

```
class Jukebox extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     youtube_urls:[],      
     clients:[],        
    };
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      this.getItems();
    }
  };

  getItems(event) {
    const {userId} = this.props
    const options = {
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/jukebox/${userId}`,
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
    };
    return axios(options)
    .then((res) => { 
      console.log(res.data)  
      console.log(res.data.data) 
      this.setState({
        clients: res.data.data[0].clients,
        youtube_urls:res.data.data[0].youtube_urls
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
  };

render() {
 const { youtube_urls } = this.state;
 return (
  <div>      
   <h1 className="title is-1">Jukebox</font></h1>
  {
   clients.map((client, index) => {
     /* 
    Obtain preview from state.previews for current artist index 
    */
    const audio = youtube_urls[index]
    /* 
    Render current client data, and corresponding audio url
    */
    return(
      <div key={index}>
      <ul>
        <ReactPlayer 
          url={ audio }
          controls
          playing // <--- does not work
          width='50'
          height='150'
        />
        <div className="Line" />
      </ul></div>
     )
   })
 })
};
```

According to to one the library props, `playing` (see above), you can play media automatically when render finishes, but if I use `map()` this will result in all videos playing at the same time.

At the same time, there is the callback prop `onReady()`:

> Called when media is loaded and ready to play. If playing is set to true, media will play immediately.

---

**QUESTION:**

How do I implement this and have all videos play, from index 0 on, one at at time, after all media is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use two state variables: `videosLoadedCount`, `playingIndex`. Initialize `videosLoadedCount` at `0` and `playingIndex` at `-1`.

You can deduce the playing props from the `playingIndex` state value.

Whenever there's an onReady, increment `videosLoadedCount`. When it reaches the number of videos, you can increment `playingIndex`. Whenever there is a `onEnded` callback, you increment `playingIndex`.

---

Something like this should work:

```
class Jukebox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loadedVideosCount: 0,
      currentPlayingIndex: -1,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { youtube_urls } = this.props;
    const { loadedVideosCount, currentPlayingIndex } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {youtube_urls.map((url, index) => (
          <ReactPlayer
            url={url}
            controls
            onLoaded={() =>
              this.setState(currentState => ({
                loadedVideosCount: loadedVideosCount + 1,
                currentPlayingIndex:
                  loadedVideosCount + 1 === youtube_urls.length ? 0 : -1,
              }))
            }
            onEnded={() =>
              this.setState(currentState => ({
                currentPlayingIndex: currentPlayingIndex + 1,
              }))
            }
            playing={index === currentPlayingIndex} // <--- does not work
            width="50"
            height="150"
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you use code? I've added my constructor. I'd accept and upvote for the kindness

Comment: why do you change youtube_urls from state to props?

Comment: I recreated the component from scratch as the syntax wasn't correct. It didn't make much sense as they was no way to add a video to the youtube_urls and having it as state might complexify the problem

Comment: For completedness sake, I've edited my components so you can understand my states. Still does not make sense? I map from `clients`, not `yoube_urls`, which user clients index...in case it helps you